# How to get the value of .NET Core CLI's --environment option

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The .NET Core CLI has an option to specify the environment using the `--environment` option, as an alternative to setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. I am trying to access the value of this option, but I am not sure how.

For some more context, I am writing a class which implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in order to get my DbContext from [a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory). I would like to be able to use the `--environment` flag to change which database connection string is used when building the `DbContext`.

At the bottom of this document it states that:

> Both IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext and Program.CreateHostBuilder accept command line arguments.
>
> You can specify these arguments from the tools:
>
> `dotnet ef database update -- --environment Production`

Usually I would use the `EnvironmentName` property of the `IHostEnvironment`, but unfortunately because I am using the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface I do not have access to an `IHostEnvironment` (that I am aware of).

I know that if I were to use the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable then I would be able to use:

```
var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

but this doesn't work when the `--environment` option is used.

At the moment I am manually parsing the `--environment` option, but this doesn't fall back nicely if no `--environment` option is passed, I could implement a fallback, but I'm starting to feel like I am over-engineering a solution to a problem that has a tidy solution built into the SDK.